# Why won't my dynamically added borders show up in IE8?

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I am dynamically adding borders to a table with this code [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYBNy/1/) and it works in FF and Chrome, but doesn't work (or throw any errors) in IE8.  Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

[EDIT]
It's not exactly an answer to the specific question, but the best solution for my real problem was dynamically setting (adding) a css class - this worked in all browsers I'm concerned with:

CSS:

```
td.bleft {
border-left:2px solid black;
}
```

JS code (where "cell" refers to a td element):

```
cell.className += " bleft";
```

Comment: I do not have IE8 on hand to test it, but have you tried using `el.style.borderRight`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update composite "convenience" styles by the individual parts. [Your fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/GYBNy/3/)

Here's the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    tbl.rows[i].cells[0].style["borderRightWidth"] = "2px";
    tbl.rows[i].cells[0].style["borderRightColor"] = "black";
    tbl.rows[i].cells[0].style["borderRightStyle"] = "solid";
}
```

Yours did not work in Firefox for me (until I changed it).

Comment: That works, too!  Do you by chance have a link discussing "convenience" styles so I can go educate myself?

Comment: @Aerik well any of the things like "border", "margin", "padding", "font", etc, where there's a list of values for different parts of the setting, apply.  Some browsers will allow them, others won't.

Answer (score 2):

As a guess, I'd try `style.borderRight` instead of `style['border-right']`.